# Espresso - Assert the text twice with same index value

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, assertion

in a screen I have the text "Available" twice.
Both has index value 1

Deveice Storage:

```
 Available
```

SD Card

```
Available
```

How i can assert this both "Available" text

Comment: what test are you using now?

Comment: onView(withText(containsString("Available"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));



like this i am trying to assert.

but i need to check whether the text "Available" is seen under both Device Storage and SD Card.

@RishabhDeepSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ViewMatcher that also references the Sibling view.

```
onView(allOf(withText(containsString("Available")), hasSibling(withText("Device Storage"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()))

onView(allOf(withText(containsString("Available")), hasSibling(withText("SD Card"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```